# Loading images to Bootstrap carousel from a MySQL database using PDO (fetchall problem)

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I'm using PDO to insert images from a database to a Bootstrap carousel. By that I mean **( loading The image path )**, but the problem is when I use `fetchall();` or `fetch` I get all rows value like this:

```
require_once '..\Config.php';

$dbCon = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name";
$conn = new PDO($dbCon, $username, $password);
$getquery = $conn->prepare('SELECT (imageurl) FROM special');
$getquery->execute();
$result = $getquery->fetchall();
echo $result['imageurl'];
```

The output is: **Efexor.jpg path upload/17.jpg upload/17.jpg upload/19.jpg upload/18.jpg upload/18.jpg*** that is all rows from imageurl column, so when I loop `foreach` (`$result`) to load images from database to a Bootstrap carousel. It dose't work

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
  <?
    $i = 0;
    foreach($result as $row){
        $actives = '';
    if($i == 0){
        $actives ='active';
    }
    ?>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?= $i; ?>" class="<?= $actives;?>"></li>
    <? $i++ ; }?>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <?
    $i = 0;
    foreach($result as $row){
        $actives = '';
    if($i == 0){
        $actives ='active';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-item  <?= $actives;?>">
      <img src="<?= $row['imageurl']?>">
    </div>
    <? echo $row['imageurl'];?>
    <? $i++; }?>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in the table `special`?  Can you check (using something like PHPMyAdmin) what the value of `imageurl` is.

Comment: @NigelRen 7 rows and the values is :- **Efexor.jpg path upload/17.jpg upload/17.jpg upload/19.jpg upload/18.jpg upload/18.jpg**

Comment: any help ..... !?

Comment: @MrObscure what is your full URL to the image path?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov !!! OMG i'm so stupid its not in the see ! [ imageurl ] path i move it to the right path and it work !!! Thanks allot

Comment: @MrObscure you are welcome, please check my answer below, and tick it as green if it works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <?
    $i = 0;
   $full_url = 'YOUR URL AND PATH TO IMAGE FOLDER HERE';
    foreach($result as $row){
        $actives = '';
    if($i == 0){
        $actives ='active';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-item  <?= $actives;?>">
      <img src="<?= $full_url . $row['imageurl']?>">
    </div>
    <? echo $full_url . $row['imageurl'];?>
    <? $i++; }?>
  </div>
```